BundleConfig not working when deployed to IIS 10.0
I have a .Net Framework 4.5 project, with Bundle Config defined.
If I run the solution locally, its able to load the CSS and Scripts properly.
Once deployed to IIS though, it cannot load and specifies 404 for the bundle config.

I tried all kinds of solutions such as :

Authentication Anonymous to use App Pool Identity
Ensure Static Content feature is enabled
Add Full Control permissions to the App Pool Identity to the folder
Web.config compilation debug=false
IgnoreList.Clear on BundleConfig

Is there anything else I can do to debug what's wrong? And find out the solution?
Below is code of registration and usage in master page:
//css
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Content/site.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/styles.css",
                    "~/Content/font-awesome.css",
                    "~/Content/jQuery.FileUpload/css/jquery.fileupload.css",
                    "~/Scripts/ernotification/ernotification.css",
                    "~/Content/css_custom.css",
                    "~/Content/ernotification.css",
                    "~/Content/signin.css"));

        //js
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/js_jquery").Include(
               "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
               "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
               "~/Scripts/moment.js",
               "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
               "~/Scripts/ernotification.js",
               "~/Scripts/modalbox/modalbox.js",
               "~/Scripts/signin.js")
               .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js")
               .Include("~/Scripts/jQuery.FileUpload/jquery.iframe-transport.js")
               .Include("~/Scripts/jQuery.FileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js")
               .Include("~/Scripts/ernotification/ernotification.js")
               );

And Application_Start
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
        {
            Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js",
            DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            CdnPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js",
            CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.js"
        });
    }

And usage:
 <%: System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/styles/bootstrap") %>
<%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/scripts/js_jquery") %>

